# Xamarin Android Login by using Password

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

MainActivity have Button "Password" When first time application is open then MainActivity should be open and user set Password using Password Activity that open by clicking Password button, Next time whenever application is open user ask to enter Password to enter in Main Activity. Kindly tell me how to perform this task. i'm new to Xamarin. here is code of Password Activity and Login Activity.i am using sqlite to save password. Thanks in advance.

Password Activity:

```
namespace App1
{
    [Activity(Label = "Password")]
    public class Password : Activity
    {
        DataBase db;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Password);
            db = new DataBase();
            Button btnSave = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnSave);
            btnSave.Click += BtnSave_Click;
        }

        private void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PasswordSave();
        }

        public void PasswordSave()
        {
            var txtPassword1 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtPassword1);
            var txtPassword2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtPassword2);
            string Pass1 = txtPassword1.Text.ToString();
            string pass2 = txtPassword2.Text.ToString();

            if (Pass1 == "" && pass2 == "")
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Empty Fields", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
            else
            {
                if (Pass1 == pass2)
                {

                    Person person = new Person()
                    {
                        password = Pass1,
                    };
                    db.insertIntoTable(person);
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Password Saved", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Please Enter the Same Password",
                        ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Login Activity Code:

```
namespace App1
{ 
    [Activity(Label = "Login")]
    public class Login : Activity
    {
        Person p;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Login);

            Button btnLogin = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.btnLogin);
            // Create your application here
            btnLogin.Click += BtnLogin_Click;
        }

        private void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var pass = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtPassword);
            string npass = pass.ToString();
            p = new Person();
            string mypass = p.password;
            if (npass == mypass)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Password Matched", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Password not Matched", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: i think you should use fragments in this case, you can find about them here in this  [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/)

Comment: I don't know , How to perform above task